# How to call myScroll.scrollToElement when the page loads

Tags: jquery, web-applications, iscroll

I am using iScroll to perform my scrolls in my webapp and are very happy with it. But in this case I need to autoscroll to a specific li at the page load, but am having no luck with it.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
var myScroll;

function loaded () {
    myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', { mouseWheel: true, click: true });
}

document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(50)'), null, null, true);
```

If I insert a link like this:

```
<a href="javascript:myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(50)'))">
```

Everything works as it should... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors that come up in the error log?

Comment: I got it!!! Just put the scrollToElement line inside function loaded()... Works like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the window.onload event to do the exact same thing you are doing in that function call
It should look something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   myScroll.scrollToElement(document.querySelector('#scroller li:nth-child(50)'), null, null, true);
}
```

[here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) are more details about the onload event (you can even attach it to html elements)

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make any change? my body tag looks like this now: <body onload="loaded()">